# Pass array values to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of input fields called '$inputFieldsArray' then I slice them to group by 3 into 'newArray' then I need new array value for each item to assign to another array cause in the end I need an array with input fields values grouped by 3. The end goal is to get an array which contains for 9 input fields ex [[i1,i2,i3],[i4,i5,i6],[i7,i8,i9]].

For some reason 'stringArray' output is nothing, first two arrays print correct results. It's probably some mistake I do regarding JS arrays.. Sorry js is not my main language, I try to learn it. Thanks.

Here is a screenshoot with chrome console:
[image]

Here is my function:

```
$($submitButton).click(function () {
// Get number of input fields
let $total = $("input[name^='bodyHeader']").length;
// Get input fields as objects
let $inputFieldsArray = $("input[name^='bodyHeader']");

let newArray = [];
let stringArray = [];
let j = 0;
// Group input fields by 3 
for (let i = 0; i < $total - 1; i += 3) {
    newArray[j] = $inputFieldsArray.slice(i, i + 3);
    j++;
}
// Extract string values from newArray and pass them into stringArray
for (let k = 0; k < newArray.length - 1; k++) {

    stringArray[k][0] = newArray[k][0].value;
    stringArray[k][1] = newArray[k][1].value;
    stringArray[k][2] = newArray[k][2].value;
}
// Print to test results
console.log($inputFieldsArray);
console.log(newArray);
console.log("String Array: " + stringArray); 
... // Function logic is not complete
});
```

**SOLUTION:**

There is no way to declare dynamic length bidimensional array in js. Use this approach suggested by @Stephan :

```
stringArray[k] = [newArray[k][0].value, newArray[k][1].value, 
newArray[k[2].value];
```

or this approach suggested by @Lorenzo Gangi:

```
var matrix = [],
cols = 3;

//init the grid matrix
for ( var i = 0; i < cols; i++ ) {
    matrix[i] = []; 
}
```

Comment: screenshots are very useful for copy + paste :/

Comment: @Jonas w , Tell me what info I should provide. Thanks.

Comment: So pressumably you have nine inputs with the name `bodyHeader` ?

Comment: @Daniel i just meant it would be easier for you and more helpful to us if you just copy the results into the post

Comment: no. tne question should never contain the answer... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringArray[k]` is undefined because you defined stringArray as `[]` (Your browser probably threw an exception). Additionally `newArray[k]` starts at index 0.

You could write `stringArray[k] = [newArray[k][0].value, newArray[k][1].value, newArray[k][2].value]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
stringArray[k]
```

is undefined yet, therefore setting its [0] property wont work. May do:

```
stringArray[k] =newArray[k].map(el=>el.value);
```

Alltogether:

```
$($submitButton).click(function () {
   let stringArray = $("input[name^='bodyHeader']").toArray().reduce((res,_,i,arr)=>((i%3==0 && res.push(arr.slice(i,i+3).map(e=>e.value))),res),[]);

});
```